# MySQL Count returns More Rows than it Should

Tags: mysql, count, rows

I am attempting to count the number of rows from a given query. But count returns more rows than it should. What is happening?

This query returns only 1 row.

```
select * 
from `opportunities` 
inner join `companies` on `opportunities`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
left join `opportunityTags` on `opportunities`.`id` = `opportunityTags`.`opportunity_id` 
where `opportunities`.`isPublished` = '1' and `opportunities`.`Company_id` = '1'
group by `opportunities`.`id` ;
```

This query returns that there are 3 rows.

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `opportunities` 
inner join `companies` on `opportunities`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
left join `opportunityTags` on `opportunities`.`id` = `opportunityTags`.`opportunity_id` 
where `opportunities`.`isPublished` = '1' and `opportunities`.`Company_id` = '1' 
group by `opportunities`.`id`;
```

Comment: How many records do You have in this table? And, check if query is counting properly if You will remove JOINs.

Comment: Despite being (irritatingly) more performative, in the absence of any aggregating functions the use of a GROUP BY clause (in your first query) is inappropriate and frequently misleading. Perhaps you were thinking of DISTINCT - although that's meaningless when used against 'SELECT *' (in a properly normalized database)

Answer (score 0):

When you select count(*) it is counting before the group by. You can probably (unfortunately my realm is SQL Server and I don't have a mySQL instance to test) fix this by using the over() function.

For example:

```
select count(*) over (partition by `opportunities`.`id`)
```

EDIT: Actually doesn't look like this is available in mySQL, my bad. How about just wrapping the whole thing in a new select statement? It's not the most elegant solution, but will give you the figure you're after.

Comment: or just deleting the answer